# change checkbox to image rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, image, checkbox

I'm trying to make a checkbox an image. Is there a way to do this with a rails tag (i.e. image_tag) or is it only through javascript/css?

Below is a sample tag...but right now just shows the image and the checkbox.  Thank you!

```
  <img src="/images/teddy-bear.jpg" align="left">
  <%= f.check_box :bear %>
```

Comment: CSS and JS is only way to do that, try something like that http://ryanfait.com/resources/custom-checkboxes-and-radio-buttons/

Comment: That seems to be good if I want a uniform type of checkbox.  Do you know of a good script for if I want each checkbox to use different images?

Comment: I have 10 checkboxes and want to use different images for each

Comment: Make a global class for all, and for each make a second class where you will specify a image.

Comment: guess that means it's not a readily available script out there..

Answer (score 1):

I ended up using this script...

http://jordankasper.com/jquery/imagecheck/examples.php

My javascript was:

```
$(function() {
$('#pin_candle')
  .simpleImageCheck({
    image: '/images/candle.jpeg',
    imageChecked: '/images/candle2.jpeg'
  })
  .change(function() {
    var c = 'checked';
    if (!$('#pin_candle').is(':checked')) {
      $(this).closest('form').submit();
    }
    $(this).closest('form').submit();
  });
});
```

My rails was:

```
<%= f.check_box :candle %>
```

It gave a checkbox image and changed to another checkbox image onclick.  Form submitted when checkbox changed.

Thank you.